# Area of a square in polar coordinates?

Tags: integration, trigonometry, polar-coordinates

I was attempting, for the exercise of it, to find the area of the a simple square with an infinite number of infinitesimal circle sectors.  Let us say this square is $[5 x 5]$.

Alas, it's been proving as awkward to compute this as it sounds.  First, I did the integral in rectangular coordinates, (much easier) $x=5$, so the area becomes $$\int_0^5 5 \space \mathrm{d}x = 25$$.

I then attempted to describe a rectangular area in polar coordinates.  I did this using $r\cos(\theta)=5$, which simplifies in terms of $\theta$ to $r=\frac{5}{\sin{\theta}}$.  Because this is a square, the angle the hypotenuse will make from the bottom left corner to the top right corner is going to be, surely, $45^{\circ}$.  This produces the integral:

$$\frac{25}{2}\int_0^\frac{\pi}{4} \frac{1}{\sin^2 (\theta)} \mathrm{d}\theta$$.

This integral does not converge according to wolfram alpha.  Would anyone be so kind as to tell me what I've done wrong?

Comment: (1) Area of strip should be $\frac{r^2}{2}d\theta$. 
(2) It should be $r\cos\theta=5$ for the limits $0$ and $\pi/4$ and $r\sin\theta=5$ for the limits $\pi/4$ and $\pi/2$.

Comment: Thanks!  I fixed that stuff.

Comment: Note that $$\frac{25}{2}\int_0^\frac{\pi}{4} \frac{1}{\cos^2 (\theta)} \mathrm{d}\theta+\frac{25}{2}\int_\frac{\pi}{4}^\frac{\pi}{2} \frac{1}{\sin^2 (\theta)} \mathrm{d}\theta=25$$

Answer (score 2):

The area of a circular sector of radius $r$ and angle $d\theta$ is $\pi r^2 \frac{d\theta}{2\pi} = \frac{1}{2} r^2 d\theta$.

The right side of the square ($0 < \theta < \pi/4$) is the line $x = 5$, which in polar coordinates is $r = \frac{5}{\cos \theta}$ (**not** $\sin$).

Putting this together, the integrand should be $\frac{1}{2}(\frac{5}{\cos \theta})^2 d\theta = \frac{25}{2 \cos^2 \theta} d\theta$.

This works out to $12.5$.  Since it only covers half of the square, double it to get the $25$ you expect.